# Using my own domain name with Gmail

Tags: gmail, pop3

I have a domain name that I bought from GoDaddy.

Is it possible for me to start an e-mail address under this domain and use Gmail for retrieving and composing mails without purchasing anything extra?

Comment: Here is a direct link from the Google Apps setup guide on configuring email: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22229&topic=22230#

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

See [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html)

With Google Apps, you won't need to create a new mailbox and forward mail or anything, you can simply create up to 50 users (for free) under your domain and use gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure you gmail to recieve mails from any other email account  ,and once you have linked another address to gmail u can send mails from gmail using the address( it comes as a dropdown option when you compose your mails)

Comment: I donot have gmail access right now , but i believe you have to go to settings and there there is a tab for pop3 , you will find everything there